# JQuery grabbing stuff from nested tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm sure this question must be answered somewhere, but well.

I got nested data I need to fetch from an HTML page. Imagine nested `<ul>`, `<li>`, `<div>` and so on.

And I need to turn them into JSON, so I'll build out the data in hierarchical Javascript objects first.

Since they are nested I would like to select the largest group, and build from there.

After I select the largest group, is there a way to further using a JQuery selector to select tag from within this larger group?

```
$('.someclass').each(function(i) {
  $(this); // what to do with this? so I select further nested data?
});
```

Comment: why not start from parent?im just curious..rather than the largest start from the top most..

Comment: what do you want to grab? HTML structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
$('#myUl li').each(function(index, item) { // you can name the item here or use "this"

  var $li = $(this);
  // an alternative way is to do:
  var $li = $(item);

  // you can select items inside the li item, for example select an anchor
  var $a = $li.find("a");
  $a.attr("href","#home");
});
```

Comment: So with `find()`, I can use any selector syntax?

Comment: Awesome! Now I finally feel like I have some control over Jquery. And thanks for $(item). Clearer.